# Use of fact that sample distribution expectation is same as population expectation

Tags: statistics, sampling

Let $P=\{p_1, p_2,\cdots, p_n\}$ be population where $p_i \in \mathbb{R}, 1 \le i \le n$.

Let $S_k \subset P$ is a sample from population $P$ of size $1 \le k < n$.

My professor told that

> we use measures calculated from samples to guess the measures of
>   population

Then I assumed that we take ***a*** subset of population and perform some function on the values of that subset to guess measures about $P$.

Then later he proved and showed us that

> Expectation for probability distribution over means of **all** samples of fixed length
>   is equal to the expectation over population

Any way we need to consider all elements from the population. In-fact sampling increases our time for computation also.

### Then what is the need for sampling here? or where I am going wrong?

---

Example he explained is

$P= \{1,2,3,4\}$

Expectation is 2.5.

By sampling of size 3 we get $\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\}\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\}$ Probabilities of corresponding samples are $1/4$ with means $6/3, 7/3, 8,3, 9/3$ and hence expectation is 2.5.

Comment: You may not have access to the whole population and may not know its mean.  So you take a sample of a pre-determined size and use the sample mean as an estimator of the population mean.   What your professor proved is that this is an *unbiased* estimator

Comment: @Henry But he is taking all subsets(samples) of size 3, which covers total population right?

Comment: That is a demonstration of the correctness of the result with a toy example.  But it is neither a proof (which would need to be more general) nor an illustration of how to use a sampling method.